# How to optimize a function with multiple characteristics?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I wish to find the a* that maximizes the following function below:

[image]

I don't think first-order conditions will work because it doesn't just involve quadratic functions.
How should you find the a* that maximizes f(a) without resorting to programming like matlab? I would appreciate some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$f(x):={90\over300-x}-{x^2\over2}$$
is a  rational function whose graph can be discussed with the standard Calculus 101 methods. It has a pole at $x=300$, where $\lim_{x\to300-} f(x)=\infty$, $\>\lim_{x\to300+} f(x)=-\infty$. This implies that $f$ is undefined at $300$, and that $f$ has no global maximum. One computes
$$f'(x)={90-90\,000x+600x^2-x^3\over(300-x)^2}\ ,$$
so that we have to solve a third degree equation for the critical points. Numerically one obtains the values
$$0.00100001,\quad 299.452,\quad300.547\ .$$
Apart from the points near $300$ one has a value very near $0$, which turns out to be a local maximum. Here is a picture of the graph:

[image]